# Speeding up large number of Random.nextint calls

Tags: java, performance, random, bufferedimage

I'm putting together a map from a tileset.  As part of that, I have a method that fills in the remainder of the map with random terrain dependant BufferedImages once the important parts have been drawn.  The `fillIn` method takes two arguments - an arraylist of BufferedImages and an ArrayList of Integers.  The Integers are of the form, for example, 90,92,94,96,98,100 and represent percentages - the two ArrayLists are of the same size and that example would mean there is a 90% chance of the first tile, a 2% of the second and so forth (actually, you'll note in my code that that isn't perfectly working either.  That's not an issue, I know how to fix it.  Just not done yet.)

The map is a thousand tiles square and populating this map is unacceptably slow.  Are there any tips or tricks for speeding this up?  Really, I'd like it unnoticeably fast.

Given the intricacy a SSCE would end up being not very Short but the code for the fillIn method is below and if any other parts would be useful then let me know.

```
    private void fillIn (ArrayList<BufferedImage> b, ArrayList <Integer> r){
    for (int i=0; i<FULLGRIDSIZE; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<FULLGRIDSIZE; j++){
            if (mapArray[i][j] ==null){
                Random rand = new Random();
                int random = rand.nextInt(100);
                for (int loopVar =0 ;loopVar<r.size();loopVar++){
                    System.out.println(random +" "+ loopVar);
                    if (random < r.get(loopVar)){
                        mapArray[i][j] = b.get(loopVar);
                        break;
                    }
                }                   
            }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void fillIn (ArrayList<BufferedImage> b, ArrayList <Integer> r){
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i=0; i<FULLGRIDSIZE; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<FULLGRIDSIZE; j++){
            if (mapArray[i][j] ==null){
                // Random rand = new Random(); Don't create so many Randoms!
                int random = rand.nextInt(100);
                for (int loopVar =0 ;loopVar<r.size();loopVar++){
                    // System.out.println(random +" "+ loopVar);
                    // printlns take a surprisingly long time
                    if (random < r.get(loopVar)){
                        mapArray[i][j] = b.get(loopVar);
                        break;
                    }
                }                   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1. You don't need a new `Random` every loop.
2. Don't `System.out.println`. It can slow down your code a surprising amount.

Comment: Whoops, sorry.  The `println` is a debugging thing so I could check the loop was working.  Overlooked the fact that I'd left it in.

Comment: Although WOW!  Taking that out makes an absolute world of difference

Comment: @MrB I know, that has happened to be before and I was surprised at the difference as well `:)` What `System.out.println` is basically doing is printing to a file (in this case the standard out), so that's why it takes so long.

Answer (score 1):

You should have one random generator object and could try to call print out only once.

```
 Random rand = new Random();

private void fillIn (ArrayList<BufferedImage> b, ArrayList <Integer> r){
    String out = "";
    for (int i=0; i<FULLGRIDSIZE; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<FULLGRIDSIZE; j++){
            if (mapArray[i][j] ==null){
                int random = rand.nextInt(100);
                for (int loopVar =0 ;loopVar<r.size();loopVar++){
                    out += random +" "+ loopVar + "\n";
                    if (random < r.get(loopVar)){
                        mapArray[i][j] = b.get(loopVar);
                        break;
                    }
                }                   
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(out);
}
```

And analyze change your random generator for http://demesos.blogspot.com/2011/09/replacing-java-random-generator.html

Answer (score 1):

I doubt the random number generation is the problem (although you should avoid creating a new `Random` instance on every iteration).

Instead, it's probably the innermost loop. Your lookup is O(n), and it should be possible to do it in O(log n). If your list size is large, this would make a massive difference, on average.

For instance, take a look at `TreeMap.lowerKey()`.